# dpkg behaving strangely?

Tags: apt, dpkg

When I use apt to get a package, I have been receiving the same error message. Here is an example trying to install wicd (which is already installed):

```
    Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
wicd is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up tex-common (2.06) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend requires a screen at least 13 lines tall and 31 columns wide.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
No packages found matching texlive-base.
dpkg: error processing tex-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-binaries:
 texlive-binaries depends on tex-common (>= 2.00); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing texlive-binaries (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dvipng:
 dvipng depends on texlive-base-bin; however:
  Package texlive-base-bin is not installed.
  Package texlive-binaries which provides texlive-base-bin is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dvipng (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
 texlive-binaries
 dvipng
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem with apt or with dpkg, but it certainly doesn't look good!

Comment: What exact command did you use?

Comment: Oof! I've been hit by a wall of text! Seems like the relevant parts are the command `sudo apt-get install tex-common` and the result `No packages found matching texlive-base.`

Comment: (That is, assuming `sudo apt-get install tex-common` was the command you ran.)

Answer (score 1):

This is usually fixed with two commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To update your database to the latest packages.

```
sudo apt-get -f upgrade
```

To upgrade and fix those packages.

Comment: The second command here worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing [texlive-base [image: Install texlive-base]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/texlive-base).

You can install it in the Software Center from that link, or in the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive-base
```

Comment: It appears that he was having a problem because `apt` couldn't find a package called `texlive-base` in any of his computer's repositories. So `apt-get install texlive-base` will probably return the same error.

Answer (score 0):

@Tshepang, Firefeater: The command was "sudo apt-get install X" where X is anything I've tried to install lately. I don't actually know whether or not I'm using the 3 packages it complains about. I certainly don't use them directly, but maybe some other thing I do use wants them.

@Javier Rivera: I ran the two commands you suggested. Many things happened, things were downloaded, and at the end, I got (again)

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
 texlive-binaries
 dvipng
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Can you add your [software sources](http://askubuntu.com/q/26047/6969) to your question?

Comment: Can you add this update the question, since it's hard to follow when spread out in additional answers/comments?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` to see if this clears the error.

If you haven't tried to purge the packages, you can try that as well:

`sudo apt-get purge texlive-base-bin`
`sudo apt-get purge  texlive-binaries`
`sudo apt-get purge tex-common`

Here's a [launchpad bug page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tex-common/+bug/536714) which I believe has relevant information.
There is also [a thread on ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1329626.html) where someone had a very similar problem.